# why is finding a point in a non-convex polygon harder than in a convex polygon?

Tags: algorithm, geospatial

I've heard a lot of people say that programmatically finding a point in a non-convex polygon is harder than finding a point in a convex polygon. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. Is this true? If so, why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you want to check whether point P is inside a polygon or outside.

If the polygon is convex, then you can iterate over each line segment making up the polygon, and check which side of that line P lies on.  P is on the inside of the polygon if it is on the right-hand side of every line segment, going clockwise.

If the polygon is concave, this algorithm doesn't work.  An algorithm that works for concave polygons is to trace from P in an arbitrary direction to infinity, and count the number of times an edge of the polygon is crossed.  P is inside the polygon if and only if the number of crossings is odd.  This algorithm has a bunch of edge cases to consider and is generally more complicated, so it will take a lot more programmer effort to write the algorithm.

In the sense that the algorithm is more difficult to write correctly, yes, it is harder.

In the sense of computational complexity, both algorithms have Θ(N) asymptotic running time.  In that sense, both problems are equally hard.

Comment: If the vertices of the convex polygon are given in sorted order, then there's an O(log n)-time algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

For a convex polygon, you can choose any point p inside the polygon (e.g. the center of mass of all the vertices) and then sort the vertices in a circular array according to the angle they make with p.  Then, given a query point x, you can compute the angle from p to x, and search through the array and find the two neighboring vertices in the array for which the angle to x is between the angles to the two vertices.  Then you compute the intersection between the line from p to x, and the edge between the two vertices.  If the distance from p to the intersection point is greater than or equal to the distance from p to x, then x is inside the polygon, otherwise x is outside the polygon.  This gives O(log n) time to determine is a point is inside or outside of a convex polygon.  On the other hand, the best known algorithm to determine if a point is inside or outside a non-convex polygon is O(n) time.  Note however you can make a hybrid algorithm depending on how much "non-convexity" you have in your polygon.  You can always decompose a polygon into a union of convex polygons, by adding extra internal edges; suppose your polygon only has a few "turns" in it and you can decompose into k convex polygons where k is small.  Then you can use the strategy for convex polygons to determine if a point is inside or outside in O(k log n) time.  So in general, the "more convexity" you have, the faster you can determine if a point is inside the polygon.